# Not able to understand the boolean logic

Tags: php, boolean

I am trying to evaluate an expression which is as follows:

```
if($x != $y)
```

Suppose the values of $x is 4 and $y is 14 then the result is true. 
But if the values of $x is 4 and $y is 04 then the result is false. 
Why this is so?

Comment: When you compare `4` to `'04'` PHP type juggles the string to an integer value, which is 4, so they are the same.

Comment: [Some test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd68bfa15ae42a48b06c474606ceb4d9dacd4957)

Comment: @AksenP Yes, I am getting the same result. i want to know why is it happening in this way. And what is the woraround for this. Because in my case if 4 != 04 should be true.